# Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT when creating a Nativescript Project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nativescript

I've been following the Nativescript tutorial [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1), but I've been having issues creating the tutorial project. I ran `tns doctor` which confirmed that my environment was set up correctly, yet I'm still getting an obscure error when attempting to create a project. Any help is appreciated

Here are the two errors I'm getting:

1.) `Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\ee\97\12f9f20988b7890bc5d892b6
f3d12771c88f9ede06c3361e81ad827bea4ddd31e5738f7723ea129e5bf110019f28f9d8d5b7670e3b68d395893e88258282'`

2.) `Command npm.cmd install nativescript-template-ng-tutorial@4.4.0 --silent --save-exact --save failed with exit code 1`

Here's the screenshot (for more context)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something might be corrupt in your npm cache. You could try:

```
npm cache clean
```

or

```
npm cache verify
```

I believe that verify is only in npm 5+.

Comment: I've run ``npm cache clean`` and ``npm cache clean -force``, but no change. I also ran ``npm cache verify`` and everything was verified with no issues. I don't know if it's worth mentioning, but I'm missing the ``\ee\`` folder in the path ``C:\Users\Nate\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\ee``.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

```
npm uninstall nativescript 
npm cache clean
npm install -g nativescript
```

Then

```
tns create HelloWorld --template nativescript-template-ng-tutorial
```

Comment: I've done this many times before, but I tried it again for good measure. Unfortunately, running it once more did not resolve my issue. I even force cleaned the cache, uninstalled, reinstalled and still had the same issue. Any ideas?